# Ложа и ложе — это родственные слова?

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова

Почитала вопрос **о райке**, и у меня возник аналогичный: а насколько родственны слова "ложе" и "ложа" (театральная, масонская и т. д.)?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

ЛОЖА (В ЗРИТЕЛЬНОМ ЗАЛЕ). Слово появилось в языке в начале 18 века. Еще в конце 17 века его не было, и П.А. Толстой (Путешествие, 1697 г-1699 г.г). пишет: «В одном театруме чуланов 200», но уже в 1733 году можно было прочитать  «сижу в одной ложе». В словарях – с 1780 года.

Слово «ложа» восходит к французскому LOGE – хижина, балаган, каморка, от древнегерманского LAUBIA -  беседка, обвитая зеленью, изначально навес, крытый берестой.   Тот же корень имеет индоевропейское слово «луб»  со значением кора, лыко, сравнить: liber (лат.) – лыко и книга. Затем идет обратное заимствование из французского языка в немецкий, а также английский: Loge (нем),  lodge (англ) – домик, сторожка.

ЛОЖА (МАСОНСКАЯ).  Ложи появились сначала в Англии (от lodge – домик), во французском языке – с 1740 года, в русском языке – из французского.

ЛОЖЕ. Это общеславянское слово (от legti), однокоренные слова лежать, лог, логово.

ЛОДЖИЯ. Слово лоджия итальянского происхождения, (итал. loggia  – беседка), но в Италии оно имеет другое значение. С 12 века лоджия является местом для собрания правления города. По конструкции лоджия представляет собой крышу, которая опирается на одну или несколько стен, роль остальных стен могут выполнять аркады, парапет, колонны. Сейчас эти лоджии являются памятниками искусства, архитектуры и культуры.

В словаре Ушакова (1935- 1940 ): Открытая галерея на колоннах вдоль стены здания. 
В словаре Ожегова (с 1949 года): 1. Открытая галерея, примыкающая к зданию. 2. Род балкона, углублённого в здание. Квартира с лоджией.

БАЛКОН. Слово балкон в переводе с латыни означает «балка». Балкон в русском языке появился в 18 веке как заимствование из французского языка (balkon), восходящее к итальянскому balkone  и древненемецкому  balko(бревно), а до этого в языке древних русичей уже  была эта балка-бревно, заимствованная напрямую от германцев.